# Use Filter function on an Object with numbers as property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to filter out a group of items from the props based on some prop. To be more specific, the `mode` prop. However, it's not filtering out the items, and I am getting **error** something like **`configs.filter` is not a function**.

I don't see anything wrong with the way I'm doing the filter here. I am trying to remove the items in the props that contain a mode prop of null.

Comment: `botconfigs.filter`  is not a function because `botconfigs` is an object (as I can see on your image) and `.filter` exists only on arrays. You can try `Object.values(botconfigs).filter` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`botConfigs` is not an array but it is an object that has numbers as it's properties.

So, you can do filter on `Object.values`:

```
filterConfigsByMode = (configId) => {
  const { botConfigs, filterBotConfigStatus } = this.props;
  const filteredList = Object.values(botConfigs).filter(item => item.mode !== null);
  return filteredList;
}
```